# Updating SQL table with values from an inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a task to update a metadata table.  We're consolidating a table which is requiring that I change the RowCountDetails field for our table with the actual row counts (this is all data coming from various text and cvs files processed by different SSIS packages and deposited into SQL Server databases)

I have the data, the row counts, but I'm not sure how to go about writing the update query.  For each file in the metadata table, I need to put the row count in the RowCountDetails column.

The row count is derived from the following:

```
SELECT  
    count(*) as 'COUNT'
    FROM SourceTable src
        LEFT JOIN #TEMPMetaData ln
                on ln.[_FileID] = src._FileID
                GROUP BY
                    src._FileID
                        ,ln.[_FileID]
                        ,ln.TableName
                        ,ln.RowCountDetail
```

This gives me what the rowcount is supposed to be for every record in the table.  And now that rowcount needs to be

I tried simply using that query in an `UPDATE` command, but it didn't work:

```
UPDATE #TEMPMetaData
    SET RowCountDetail = (SELECT  
                            count(*) as 'COUNT'
                            FROM SourceTable src
                                    LEFT JOIN #TEMPMetaData ln
                                            on ln.[_FileID] = src._FileID
                            GROUP BY
                                    src._FileID
                                        ,ln.[_FileID]
                                        ,ln.TableName
                                        ,ln.RowCountDetail)
    WHERE TableName = 'SourceTable'
```

And it failed because it's trying to put all the results of that query into one field, which is what I suspected would happen

Essentially what I need is, for each `_FileID`, I need to move the value of `COUNT` from that SELECT command into the #TEMPMetaData RowCountDetails column

I'm not sure what the appropriate SQL solution to this is.  Or should I look to using C# for a solution (Like ADO)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE t
    SET RowCountDetail = (SELECT count(*)
                          FROM SourceTable src
                          WHERE t.[_FileID] = src._FileID
                         )
    FROM #TEMPMetaData t
    WHERE t.TableName = 'SourceTable';
```